# In Out parameters in Dynamic SQL DB2

Tags: db2

I want to write a dynamic SQL in DB2. There is an input parameter (`cID`) and an output parameter (`nsalary`).

```
   Declare cID varchar(5) ;
   Declare nsalary integer ;
   Declare csql varchar(200) ;
   
   Set cID = '111' ;

   Csql = ‘select salary from Employeee where ID = :cID’ ;
   Exec immediate csql into nsalary using cID ;
```

Does it work. I don't have server, so I can't test

Comment: How is it possible to write code without a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your code won't work.
You can't use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with a parameterized query and must use `PREPARE` & `EXECUTE` instead. Moreover, you have to use dynamic `SET` statement.
Look at the example below.

```
...
Set cID = '111' ;
SET Csql = 'SET ? = (select salary from Employee where ID = :cID)' ;
PREPARE S1 FROM Csql;
EXECUTE S1 into nsalary using cID;
```

Answer (score 0):

my table is aaa (a char(5))

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE zzz ()
      DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
     P1: BEGIN
          Declare cID char(5) ;
          Declare cc char(5) ;
          Declare csql varchar(200) ;
            Declare s1 varchar(200) ;

             Set cID = 'a' ;

             SET Csql = 'SET ? = (select a from aaa where a = :cID)' ;

           PREPARE S1 FROM Csql  ;       
             EXECUTE S1 into cc using cID ;     {error this line}

      print (cc) ;
   END P1
```

Deploy [sss]A.ZZZ

Running
A.ZZZ - Deploy started.
Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
A.ZZZ: 14: An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "S1 into cc using cID".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56
An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "S1 into cc using cID".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56
A.ZZZ - Deploy failed.
A.ZZZ - Roll back completed successfully.

Comment: i can't ask new question.Because i reach permission.The quesion is the same meaning.Becasue i want to see in out parameters in Dynamic SQL